# Edit messages in midi file without re-encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi, mido

I'm using the mido library. I have a midi file and I want to change its messages. I don't want to encode messages using the `Message()` function because I already have it encoded in the form: `<message note_on channel=0 note=44 velocity=64 time=0>`. I've tried appending this to the track, but it reads it as a string instead of a message, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't "tag" your titles. Stack Overflow has real tags, which are perfectly sufficient.

Comment: The messages should be `Message` objects. Where do you get the string from?

Comment: I edited the messages by printing them and manually editing them in a text editor. I guess my question is, how do I convert a string message to a ```Message``` message. Or maybe there's a better way to edit the messages.